# Change event of jQuery UI autocomplete not working

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to get the change event of the autocomplete jquery ui widget to work but it doesn't seem to run when the user erases the field. Here is what I have:

```
$("#clientInput").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,

    ...
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.item === null)  {
            $(".one_third").load("Order/OrderBook", { client: "" });
        }
    }
});
```

It seems to work when the text changes from one value to another but not when the user erases the field. What should I be doing?

Comment: Works for me ...http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/633/

Comment: if you erase the field and press tab the change event does not execute.

Comment: If that is the case then use `$(this).blur();` on select event of AC.